# Sprites aren't appearing

Tags: python, class, pygame, subclass, sprite

My sprites(tokens) aren't appearing on the screen. I included all of my code incase something in the body of the code is messing it up. I put in stars the code that directly had to do with the token sprites. The gist of the code is: three blocks appear on screen, and right now I'm trying to make either 11, 15, or 21 tokens (orange 20x20 pixel squares) appear spread out in the middle circle. They are not showing up. Ignore the code about the arrow keys as that is for later. My first priority is getting the sprites appearing, but if you have any suggestions to speeding up or better organizing my code I'd love to hear it! Thanks.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))

gray = pygame.Color(220, 220, 220)
black = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)
blue = pygame.Color(0, 0, 255)
red = pygame.Color(255, 0 ,0)
white = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)


t_end = time.time() + 60*15

g=0

f = open("results", "a")
f.write("trial number, answer, reaction time, correct answer, number of balls in left circle at response, number of balls in middle circle at response, number of balls in right circle at response\n")
f.close()

**class tokens(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

token_list = pygame.sprite.Group()**

while time.time() < t_end:
    screen.fill(gray)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, Rect((30,140), (200,200)))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, Rect((260,140), (200,200)))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, Rect((490,140), (200,200)))
    pygame.display.update()

    **n = random.randint(1,3)
    if n == 1:
        n=11
    elif n == 2:
        n = 15
    elif n == 3:
        n = 21

    x_coords = [35, 75, 115, 155, 195, 35, 75, 115, 155, 195,  35, 75, 115, 155, 195,  35, 75, 115, 155, 195]

    y_coords = [170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 210, 210, 210, 210, 210, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290]


    for i in range(0,n):
        token = tokens((255,120,0), 20, 20)
        token.rect.x = x_coords[i-1]
        token.rect.y = y_coords[i-1]

        token_list.add(token)**

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            g+=1
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                answer = "left"
                f = open("results", "a")
                f.write(str(g) + ", left\n")
                f.close()
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, Rect((30,140), (200,200)))
                print("You picked left!")
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(1)
                screen.fill(black)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(1)

            elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                answer = "right"
                f = open("results", "a")
                f.write(str(g) + ", right\n")
                f.close()
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, Rect((490,140), (200,200)))
                print("You picked right!")
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(1)
                screen.fill(black)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the sprites to the `token_list` sprite group, but you never actually draw them on.

The easiest way is to just call `token_list.draw(screen)` before updating the screen.

Also, your event handling is messed up. E.g. there's no need to get all pressed keys with `pygame.key.get_pressed()` if you already catch the `KEYDOWN` event. Just check `event.key` for `K_LEFT` or `K_RIGHT`.